# My DatePickerDialog not showing the current date. How to get Current date in DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I used TimepickerDialog and DatePicker Dialog to get the Time and Date.
But when open the Date Picker Dialog it showing different date [click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYhV9.png)

Here is my code.

```
         final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            dt_day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            dt_month =calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            dt_year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
           final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                 //     datePickerDialog.updateDate(12,12,1993);
                date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month+1) + "/" + year);
                str_date = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month+1) + "/" + year);
            }
        },dt_day, dt_month,dt_year);

        datePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have given wrong values in parameter, the third parameter should be dt_year and the fifth parameter should be dt_day